# Using C# to validate a TextBox using Regex and changing Texbox back color

Tags: c#, .net, regex, textbox

I'm using `winForms` to validate the first name using `regex`. I have a `textbox` and a `button` in my form. When you click on the `button`, the program checks if the user typed a valid first name. If the user typed a invalid first name the `textbox` will change its color. I have a method that if the user types in a valid first name the textbox will change to its original color 'white'

for example:

valid first name : Z

invalid first name : 1

The issue I'm having is that my program does not recognize the the validation instantly. (eng. If I typed in the letter Z, the textbox will still be a the color Red.) Its not until I pressed another key like the "space bar", "backspace", letter "H" or anything else for my program to realize that the letter Z is a valid first name.

What is going on here? In the picture below Z should be valid, but like I said previously I have to type in another key for my program to recognize that the first name is valid.

```
//checks if Regex code is wrong if so change the textbox color
    public void Error_Checker()
    {
        if (First_Name_Regex.FNameRegx.IsMatch(textBox1.Text) == false)//First Name Validation
        {
            textBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
        } 
    }
    //if the RegexCode is comes out true change color
    private void textbox_White(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (First_Name_Regex.FNameRegx.IsMatch(textBox1.Text))//First Name Validation
        {
            textBox1.BackColor = Color.White;

        }
    }
    //textBox1 first name Regex validator
    public static class First_Name_Regex 
    {
        public static readonly Regex FNameRegx = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z]+$");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Error_Checker();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I should say that validating first names with regex is something really worthless. What about `Саша`? In Ukrainian, an apostrophe is considered a letter.

Comment: I'm validating many things like phone numbers, ssn,  but for simplicity, I wanted to keep the question short. @stribizhev

Comment: Ok, at least use `[\p{L}\p{M}]` to check for just letters. Then, to perform live validation, you need to specify `TextChanged` event and add your validation code there.

Comment: @stribizhev Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
if ( (new Regex(@"^[A-Za-z]+$")).IsMatch(textBox1.Text) )
{
    textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
}
else
{
    textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```

And it should be inside a `TextChanged` event